# How to color cells in column A if cells in other columns relating to those column A cells are filled in?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

Column A contains student names. The other columns show work that is missing or incomplete.

I'd like to be able to have cells in column A colored in if work from various classes is missing, without setting individual conditional assignments for each column (other than A). I don't know how to refer to all the other columns in ONE formula.

Answer (score 1):

- custom formula is: **`=COUNTIF($B2:$Z2, "=missing")`**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the response.  However, what if instead of "missing," the cell is blank?  How would you modify the formula in that case?

Comment: Okay, Thanks. I'll give it a try.  Thanks again for the prompt response.

Comment: Okay, I tried that, but every student's name cell is yellow, even those who don't have missing work.  Also, I changed the COUNTBLANK part to $B3:$Z3 because there are two rows of header information for each assignment.

Comment: @user2888382 try: `=IF(AND(LEN($A3), COUNTBLANK($B3:$Z3)>0), 1)` https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibMg3.png

Comment: Thanks again, but it's still turning ALL the names yellow. I really appreciate you trying to help me with this. I wish I knew more about scripts and formulae!

Comment: can you share a copy/dummy of your sheet?

Comment: Not sure how to do that within this forum.  Does this work for you?  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rfDS6iVVcKvx9hbEE04L7N86z2TeO6kjP5Z4AKQd9-I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: its done. check your sheet